# How can realm from Non-UI thread invoking changelistener from UI thread?

Tags: android, multithreading, realm

I have two realm instances one in Non-UI thread and other in UI thread, I am updating realm values in `Non-UI thread` but how the change listener is getting invoked in `UI` thread?

Actually, I want this functionality to happen but in docs, I read that this cannot happen as different realm instances in different thread have different copies of data if they are created in different threads?

Comment: `but how the change listener is getting invoked in UI thread?` Realm handles that in the object store. On your end, all you see is that your RealmChangeListener works as you expect (with some slight delay, anyway).

Comment: @EpicPandaForce So, it will always work? Because in docs it is not mentioned anywhere

Comment: Why wouldn't it work? As long as the RealmResults is kept as field reference in your class, like `private RealmResults<T> results;` then it'll work.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I am in doubt as they are created in two different threads.

Comment: Well. Try it. It's always worked for me... :D

Comment: Yes, it is indeed, but I just wanted to see in the documentation.

Comment: See https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#auto-refresh and https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#notifications